# No CSS and theme in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I have imported as usual my website to work on it in localhost ! this time my site display no CSS no theme, just text. [image: local]

the online version is : [image: online]

This is magento 1.9.x

do you have any suggestions please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to follow these steps:

1. clear the root/var/cache folder
2. Uncompress the minified CSS and Js
3. check if you are not using any CDN module to load the media.
4. Check the base url and Media URL are pointing to localhost.
5. Change any of above configuration if do not find correct.

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change secure and unsecure url form the admin panel under the general tab.

Follow steps

System > Configrution > General > 
Change secure and unsecure url

I hop it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the secure and unsecure url from database table name '#__core_config_data' path value for both url is 'web/unsecure/base_url' and 'web/secure/base_url'. Also remove the cache from var folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes issues occurs while working on Localhost Use url as 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and follow above answer steps.

Answer (score 0):

after seeing this its look like this is permission issue

reset permission by following command, fire below command in your magento root folder

```
chmod -R 644 ./*
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod 550 ./mage
```

and also check skin url in your database `core_config_data` table

1) Login admin panel

2) go to `Sytem->Configuration->General->Web-> Unsecure`

3) change `Base Skin URL` to `{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/`

4) `Sytem->Configuration->General->Web-> Secure`

5) for this also `Base Skin URL` to `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`

6) go to `system->Cache Management` and Refresh the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Check the root directory for the media folder, if it isn't there try creating it then clear caches and try again.

It's likely to be one of the other fixes mentioned, but there have been a few instances where this happens if you don't have a media folder.